# Xcode does not run pre-written C++ files

Tags: c++, xcode

So basicly I have my cpp files written in Code::Blocks, and I need to run them on Xcode.
The problem starts when i open the file in Xcode, I can see the code, but when I go to menu -> product menus like run and build is greyed out, but when I creat new projects and choose command line tool and then choose C++ and rewrite code there, I am able to run it, but imageing when the code is realy long, what do I do then?

Comment: Do you have a build target, and c++ files registered to said target?

Comment: You need to add the files to the Xcode project in order for it to compile them. Xcode doesn't know what to do with a single source file on its own that hasn't been associated with a project.

Comment: @NathanS. so there is no way I can just double click cpp file and then press run, everytime I need to start a new project and add that file to it to run? if thats so, is there some other alternative tools to xcode that can do that?

Comment: @eLbor: Compile them from command line and run.

Comment: @eLbor Nope; you need a project to be able to run things in Xcode.

Comment: g++ somefile.cpp -o someobject && ./someobject

Comment: This seems very much a case of RTFM.  FYI you wouldn't get the behaviour your describe in Visual Studio either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode needs files to be added to a project to be able to run them. If you want don't want to use a project, you can use g++ from the command line:

```
g++ -o myExecutable myFile.cpp
```

You can then run:

```
./myExecutable
```

This is easy for single files, but Xcode is easier when your projects have dozens or hundreds of files.